# Two equal table cells, different available space for content?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table with monotype text and I noticed that sometimes content from one cell won't fit into another cell that should be the same size. 
Can someone explain to me why that is or how I can fix this? See example below, where I try to put the same amount of "-" into both cells. In the first cell, it won't fit so the last "-" gets shifted into the next line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="font-family: Courier; table-layout:fixed; width:468px; margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse">

      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6">------------------------</td>

        <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6">------------------------</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the last "-" doesn't shift to the next line

Comment: well, it does on my system, even with the "run code snippet".

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to wrap your content into cell width.

```
table td {width:100px; word-wrap:break-word;}
```

```css
table td {width:100px; word-wrap:break-word;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="font-family: Courier; table-layout:fixed; width:468px; margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse">

      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;" >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>

        <td style="border: 1px solid black;" >---------------------------</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="font-family: Courier; table-layout:fixed; width:468px; margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse">

      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding:5px 0" colspan="6">------------------------</td>

        <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6">------------------------</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 1px to the width (469 instead of 468) and it will fit. 
I think the problem might be the 1px border, between the two td, that get's 1px of space in the row. 
[first td(233px) | border 1px | second td (234px)] = 233 + 1 + 234 = 468

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="font-family: Courier; table-layout:fixed; width:469px; margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse">

      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6">------------------------</td>

        <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6">------------------------</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: okay, thanks. that might actually be the reason for this. adding 1px with wil make it fit but then the space between the last "-" and the end of the cell will be different in both cells. I guess I'll have to live with that but it surprises me a little.

Comment: mhh from the code snippet it looks quite similar, maybe in other resolutions it might look different. But if i can suggest you something, you can try with bootstrap columns, they make a pretty good work. Here's the page documententation link [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns).